# PyQT5 - mix VBox and HBox Layout?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I created the following windows which generally works fine:

[image]

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QComboBox, QDialog,
QDialogButtonBox, QFormLayout, QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout,
QLabel, QLineEdit, QMenu, QMenuBar, QPushButton, QSpinBox, QTextEdit,
QVBoxLayout)

import sys

class Dialog(QDialog):
    NumGridRows = 3
    NumButtons = 4

    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()
        self.createFormGroupBox()
        
        self.Button1 = QPushButton(self)
        self.Button1.setText("Calc")
        self.Button2 = QPushButton(self)
        self.Button2.setText("Reset")

        # buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        # buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        # buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)
        
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.formGroupBox)
        # mainLayout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.Button1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.Button2)
                    
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)        
        self.setWindowTitle("Form Layout")
        
    def createFormGroupBox(self):
        self.formGroupBox = QGroupBox("Form layout")
        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Name:"), QLineEdit())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Country:"), QComboBox())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Age:"), QSpinBox())
        self.formGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Dialog()
    sys.exit(dialog.exec_())
```

The only thing I would like to change is that the buttons are horizontally arranged under the form layout and not vertically.

How can I achieve that to mix a vertical box with a horizontally box inside?

Comment: Create a QHBoxLayout, add the buttons to it, and then `mainLayout.addLayout(hlayout)`.

Comment: Yes that worked - when you write a answer i will approve it as solution if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Qt [layout manager](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) is a "container" of [QLayoutItems](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayoutitem.html), which are abstract items that represent visual objects that can be *layed out*.
Those items usually contain a Qt widget, but they can also be other objects, like spacers ([QSpacerItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspaceritem.html)) or even other layouts (note that QLayout actually inherits from QLayoutItem).

You can actually do *nested layouts*.

The solution to your problem is actually pretty easy:

1. create a horizontal layout;
2. add the buttons to that layout;
3. add the layout to the *main* layout;

```
class Dialog(QDialog):
    NumGridRows = 3
    NumButtons = 4

    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Form Layout")

        self.createFormGroupBox()
        
        # QLayout(widget) automatically sets the layout on "widget" so you
        # don't need to call widget.setLayout()
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.formGroupBox)

        self.button1 = QPushButton("Calc")
        self.button2 = QPushButton("Reset")

        buttonLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.button1)
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.button2)
        mainLayout.addLayout(buttonLayout)
```

Notes:

- when widgets are going to be added to a layout, there's no point in providing the widget argument (`self`, in this case), as adding them to a layout that is set on a widget automatically reparents them;
- only classes and constants should have capitalized names, not variables, functions or instance attributes (that's why I changed `button1` and `button2`); remember that readability is *very* important, see the official [Style Guide for Python Code](//python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) to know more;
- QDialogButtonBox is a QWidget on its own, with its internal layout; you can still use it for custom buttons, though; for instance, you could change the text of the `Ok` button doing `buttonBox.button(buttonBox.Ok).setText("Calc")`; or you could add a custom button by doing `okButton = QPushButton("Calc")` and `buttonBox.addButton(okButton, buttonBox.AcceptRole)`; please carefully study the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialogbuttonbox.html) to better understand the behavior of that class;